# Dotnet-outdated Permission Denied

Tags: c#, jenkins, .net-core

Im using an a dotnet image in jenkins in order to execute dotnet-outdated command

here is my image code

```
FROM /baseimages/microsoft/dotnet/core/sdk:6.0-alpine  //this link is private i cannot share but he gives the dotnet image


RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-outdated-tool --version 4.1.0
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"


ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
```

i get the image from harbor, when i tried the image on docker, the command run without a problem, but when i try it on jenkins it doesnt work

here is the code in jenkins

```
stage('getFolder') {                        
                    container('dotnet-outdated') {
                        sh """
                        dotnet --version
                        dotnet-outdated --version
                    """
                    }
                }
```

the dotnet --version works fine
but the dotnet outdated doesnt work
this is the error
[image: error]

the environment is already set

```
envVars: [
            envVar(key: 'DOTNET_CLI_HOME', value: '/tmp/dotnet_cli'),
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using --global see msdn for full reference(
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)

Your package is installed at **~/.nuget(.dotnet)/packages(tools)**.

Which is most likely can not be accessed because of one of the following:

- no access for user running to the PATH
- the PATH is not in $PATH variables list

You can check actual PATHs with:

```
dotnet nuget locals all --list
```

Generally to avoid this sort of issue I would use tool-path and provide custom path for installation (i.e. **./tools**, avoiding user folder, so there is no need to have access to **root** in runtime) in combination with adding destination folder to $PATH list. Afterwards a permissions for folder need to be updated (read/write with **chmod**).

**EDIT 1**: Tested setup

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0


RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-outdated-tool --version 4.1.0
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

RUN dotnet help

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet-outdated" ]
```

Output: Discovering projects...The directory '/' does not contain any solutions or projects.

Comment: I modified the image to this 
```
RUN dotnet tool install dotnet-outdated-tool --version 4.1.0 --tool-path "./tools"
RUN chmod +rwx "./tools"
ENV PATH="$PATH:./tools"

RUN dotnet tool install dotnet-outdated-tool --version 4.1.0 --tool-path "./tools"
RUN chmod +rwx "./tools"
ENV PATH="$PATH:./tools"

```
still didnt work

Comment: @omarsalhi I have tried a very simple setup  see EDIT1 in my answer. That's a clear indication of issue with paths. You are setting DOTNET_CLI_HOME variable from Jenkins to temp. Which means that tool will search for projects under that path, but did you chmod it?

Comment: no I didnt, so i need to change the path and then chmod it ?

Comment: Tools are user-specific, not machine global. https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2018/05/12/dotnet-global-tools/#installing-the-net-core-cli-into-a-non-default-location more details here. The trick with PATH and extra folder is to make them global. Dotnet tools rely on DOTNET_ROOT variable to be correct, I assume that your base image is okay. The scanning part of dotnet-outdated invoke home folder and possible packages folder. I assume your image setting packages folder correctly since they out of concern. The only thing left is access to temp folder

Comment: @omarsalhi post errors that you see. :)